# How to keep border radius constant when resize is used in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

The project uses a logo that is being resized and its border-radius changes when resized. this app is based on music in Xcode.

The logo has a round rectangle shape and has a padding of 90 from the top on a rendered page. when the padding is reduced to 10 the shape remains the same but the size doesn't decrease as it should.

Logo created :

```
Image("large_logo")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(minWidth: logo_minSize, idealWidth: logo_idealSize, maxWidth: logo_maxSize, minHeight: logo_minSize, idealHeight: logo_idealSize, maxHeight: logo_maxSize, alignment: .center)
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous))
        .padding(15)
}
```

padding is given to the logo:

```
RechordLogo().padding(.top,10)
```

Comment: could you post before/after screenshot?

Comment: How about using `Capsule`? It resizes dynamically.